# Grothendieck's double limit criteria for weakly compact set

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-algebras

I was reading about Arens regularity of normed algebras in Palmer's book. He talks about the Grothendieck's double limit criteria for relatively weak compact sets in $X^*$ . Can some one provide me a proof or a link to an English version of his paper "Criteres de compacite' dans les espaces fonctionnels ge'ne'raux" ?

Comment: Have you looked in Grothendieck's *Topological Vector Spaces*?